# How to set up a Mock to test IF a method is called based on a condition in the CUT

Tags: delphi

Delphi 10.3.3
Delphi.Mocks

I am having trouble setting up a test to tell if a method in the Mock has been called based on a condition. As a simple example included here. I want to know if MyObject.PlaceOrder is called when MyProjectObject.CheckOutOurStock is called and the stock is empty. CheckOutOurStock calls MyObject.PlaceOrder if IsStockEmpty is true. I want the test to fail if I comment out the call to MyObject.PlaceOrder.

Setting up the mock with Expect (MockMyObject.Setup.Expect.Once.when.PlaceOrder;) doesn't work of course because of the when arg. Leaving off the when and just MockMyObject.Setup.Expect.Once doesn't work either.

I would like to simply set a flag LPlaceOrderWasCalled : Boolean and Assert against that.

I suspect what I am after is in the WillExecute setup but I don't know how to do it. I included the method signature commented out in the test. A simple procedure would work but that is not what WillExecute expects. I have only found examples that show the signature no concrete examples.

Any help would be appreciated

```
unit MyObject;

interface

type
    TMyObject = class     
  public
        procedure PlaceOrder;
  end;

implementation

{ TMyObject }

procedure TMyObject.PlaceOrder;
begin
//  Place an order
end;    
end.

unit MyProjectObject;

interface
uses
    MyObject;

type
    TMyProjectObject = class
    private
        FMyObject: TMyObject;
        FIsStockEmpty: Boolean;
    public
        procedure CheckOutOurStock;
        property MyObject: TMyObject read FMyObject write FMyObject;
        property IsStockEmpty: Boolean read FIsStockEmpty write FIsStockEmpty;
    end;

implementation

{ TMyProjectObject }

procedure TMyProjectObject.CheckOutOurStock;
begin
    if IsStockEmpty then
//    MyObject.PlaceOrder;
end;
end
```

The test:

```
procedure
        TMyProjectObjectTest.CheckOutOurStock_WhenIsStockEmptyIsTrue_PlacesOrder;
var
    MockMyObject : TMock<TMyObject>;
  LPlaceOrderWasCalled : Boolean;
begin
  //Arrange
  LPlaceOrderWasCalled := False;
  MockMyObject := TMock<TMyObject>.Create;

  MockMyObject.Setup.Expect.Once.when.PlaceOrder;

    MockMyObject.Setup.WillExecute(
    function(const args: TArray<TValue>; const ReturnType: TRttiType)
    begin
            LPlaceOrderWasCalled := True;
      Result :=  '';
    end).when.PlaceOrder;

  Cut.MyObject := MockMyObject;
  CUT.IsStockEmpty := True;

  //Act
  CUT.CheckOutOurStock;

  //Assert
  Assert.WillNotRaise(
        procedure
        begin
            MockMyObject.Verify();
        end, EMockVerificationException);

  Assert.IsTrue(LPlaceOrderWasCalled);

//  TExecuteFunc = reference to function (const args : TArray<TValue>; const ReturnType : TRttiType) : TValue;
end;


.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot mock non virtual methods.

Comment: Stefan, I had this problem about a month ago with my first attempt to verify if a procedure was called being frustrated I built a workaround. Now with more time I tried to investigate further. I always use interfaces but didn't in this example for some reason. After your comment I changed it around to use interface and repost, but of course it worked as expected. The test was more complicated and if the mock was not called did something else. This caused access violation (The real problem but only in the test), I gave up. Now I know how to use it. Thank you